# NetTopologySuite ShapeDataReader Error: Unsupported DBF reader Type 13

Tags: c#, .net-core, shapefile, nettopologysuite

I'm trying to read an .shp that I created from [geojson.io](http://geojson.io) to do some tests, it gave me an .zip which contains the files below.

When I try to read the .shp alone I'm having the error: "System.IO.FileNotFoundException: '.../POLYGON.dbf'". 
When I try to read the .shp with the .dbf in the same folder I'm having the error: "System.NotSupportedException: 'Unsupported DBF reader Type 13'".

I tried to open this .shp in QGIS and it worked.
I tried to read other .shp files from other sources with my code and it worked.

Code:

```
ShapeDataReader reader = new ShapeDataReader("...\\POLYGON.shp");
```

Files:
[POLYGON.dbf](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1tDu2mPkbhl-X6dNxbMsyINZLE-qRjR3v)
[POLYGON.prj](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1pSWtfMDjrd3vUCJ06K8uWXYM9MhFuj6x)
[POLYGON.shp](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1CUvh7jCkCi04j3DJWS_l0x2D6ih0xgUs)
[POLYGON.shx](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1zSNgYBm6wfVWx0fh_-u-6q6hXbTx7zX4)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the inline [docstrings](https://github.com/NetTopologySuite/NetTopologySuite.IO.ShapeFile/blob/develop/src/NetTopologySuite.IO.ShapeFile/ShapefileDataReader.cs#L31) provided by NTS, `ShapeDataReader` constructor takes in the shapefile path without the `.shp` file extension, hence try the following:

`ShapeDataReader reader = new ShapeDataReader("...\\POLYGON")`