# Reading wkt, kml and shapefile with dotnet core 2.2

Tags: c#, .net-core, geospatial

I'm new on dealing with geospatial data and I'm working on a dotnet core 2.2 project. I need to receive a file (that can be an wkt, kml or shapefile), read it and send back the coordinates.

I tried NetTopologySuite but apparently there are some types of shapefiles that can't be read with it (as I explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59655295/nettopologysuite-shapedatareader-error-unsupported-dbf-reader-type-13)).

I would like to know about options for doing this kind of processing that are compatible with dotnet core 2.2.

Comment: kml is xml format (text file that can be read with notepad) and you can use any Net xml library method to read file.

Comment: @jdweng Thanks for the answer. Reading kml and wkt file seems preety simple, I'm having problems with the shapefiles.

Comment: Are the shapefiles binary or text?  If binary, is there a text header in the binary that give any useful info (read with notepad)?  Not sure what the format is of the file.

Answer (score 0):

For KML I use https://github.com/samcragg/sharpkml library. As for SHP I would be interested myself :-) because so far everything I find is not portable (i.e. Windows only).